# Change the start position of cross hair matplotlib cursor example

Tags: python, matplotlib

The snapping cursor when plotted starts at (0,0) making my graph very small.

[It's doing this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG2hw.png)

[Instead of this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r14H4.png)

I think that the code is made so that initially the cross hair starts at (0,0), but I don't know how to change that.

The code for the Snapping Cursor ([link here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/cursor_demo.html#snapping-to-data-points)):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class SnappingCursor:
    """
    A cross hair cursor that snaps to the data point of a line, which is
    closest to the *x* position of the cursor.

    For simplicity, this assumes that *x* values of the data are sorted.
    """
    def __init__(self, ax, line):
        self.ax = ax
        self.horizontal_line = ax.axhline(color='k', lw=0.8, ls='--')
        self.vertical_line = ax.axvline(color='k', lw=0.8, ls='--')
        self.x, self.y = line.get_data()
        self._last_index = None
        # text location in axes coords
        self.text = ax.text(0.72, 0.9, '', transform=ax.transAxes)

    def set_cross_hair_visible(self, visible):
        need_redraw = self.horizontal_line.get_visible() != visible
        self.horizontal_line.set_visible(visible)
        self.vertical_line.set_visible(visible)
        self.text.set_visible(visible)
        return need_redraw

    def on_mouse_move(self, event):
        if not event.inaxes:
            self._last_index = None
            need_redraw = self.set_cross_hair_visible(False)
            if need_redraw:
                self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()
        else:
            self.set_cross_hair_visible(True)
            x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
            index = min(np.searchsorted(self.x, x), len(self.x) - 1)
            if index == self._last_index:
                return  # still on the same data point. Nothing to do.
            self._last_index = index
            x = self.x[index]
            y = self.y[index]
            # update the line positions
            self.horizontal_line.set_ydata(y)
            self.vertical_line.set_xdata(x)
            self.text.set_text('x=%1.2f, y=%1.2f' % (x, y))
            self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()


x = np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)
y = np.sin(2 * 2 * np.pi * x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('Snapping cursor')
line, = ax.plot(x, y, 'o')
print(line)
snap_cursor = SnappingCursor(ax, line)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', snap_cursor.on_mouse_move)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to set the initial position of the horizontal line. The `__init__()` should be:

```
def __init__(self, ax, line):
    self.ax = ax
    self.x, self.y = line.get_data()
    self.horizontal_line = ax.axhline(y=self.y[0], xmin=self.x[0], xmax=self.x[-1], color='k', lw=0.8, ls='--')
    self.vertical_line = ax.axvline(color='k', lw=0.8, ls='--')
    self._last_index = None
    # text location in axes coords
    self.text = ax.text(0.72, 0.9, '', transform=ax.transAxes)
```

That worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
    self.horizontal_line = ax.axhline(y=1000,color='k', lw=0.8, ls='--')
    self.vertical_line = ax.axvline(x=2000, color='k', lw=0.8, ls='--')
```

use the "y = "and "x=" or whatever coordinates you wish in **init** function. Definitely will work.